# cv.glmnet fails for ridge, not lasso, for simulated data with coder error

Tags: r, glmnet

### Gist

The error:  `Error in predmat[which, seq(nlami)] = preds : replacement has length zero`

The context: data is simulated with a binary y, but there are `n` coders of `true y`. the data is stacked `n` times and a model is fitted, trying to get `true y`.

The error is received for

1. `L2` penalty, but not `L1` penalty.
2. when Y is the coder Y, but not when it is the true Y.
3. the error is *not* deterministic, but depends on seed.

UPDATE: the error is for versions after 1.9-8. 1.9-8 does not fail.

### Reproduction

#### base data:

```
library(glmnet)
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(123)

num_obs=4000
n_coders=2
precision=.8

X <- matrix(rnorm(num_obs*20, sd=1), nrow=num_obs)
prob1 <- plogis(X %*% c(2, -2, 1, -1, rep(0, 16))) # yes many zeros, ignore
y_true <- rbinom(num_obs, 1, prob1)
dat <- data.frame(y_true = y_true, X = X)
```

#### create coders

```
classify <- function(true_y,precision){
  n=length(true_y)
  y_coder <- numeric(n)
  y_coder[which(true_y==1)] <- rbinom(n=length(which(true_y==1)),
                                      size=1,prob=precision)
  y_coder[which(true_y==0)] <- rbinom(n=length(which(true_y==0)),
                                      size=1,prob=(1-precision))
  return(y_coder)
}
y_codings <- sapply(rep(precision,n_coders),classify,true_y = dat$y_true)
```

#### stack it all

```
expanded_data <- do.call(rbind,rep(list(dat),n_coders))
expanded_data$y_codings <- matrix(y_codings, ncol = 1)
```

#### reproduce error

Since the error depends on seed, a loop is necessary. only the first loop will fail, the other two will finish.

```
X <- as.matrix(expanded_data[,grep("X",names(expanded_data))])

for (i in 1:1000) cv.glmnet(x = X,y = expanded_data$y_codings,
                            family="binomial", alpha=0)  # will fail
for (i in 1:1000) cv.glmnet(x = X,y = expanded_data$y_codings,
                            family="binomial", alpha=1)  # will not fail
for (i in 1:1000) cv.glmnet(x = X,y = expanded_data$y_true,
                            family="binomial", alpha=0)  # will not fail
```

Any thoughts where this is coming from in glmnet and how to avoid it? from my reading of `cv.glmnet`, this is after the cv routine and is inside `cvstuff = do.call(fun, list(outlist, lambda, x, y, weights, offset, foldid, type.measure, grouped, keep))`, which I do not understand its role, hence the failure, and how to avoid it.

sessions (Ubuntu and PC)

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] glmnet_2.0-2    foreach_1.4.3   Matrix_1.2-7.1  devtools_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1       R6_2.2.0         tools_3.3.1      withr_1.0.2      curl_2.1        
 [6] memoise_1.0.0    codetools_0.2-15 grid_3.3.1       iterators_1.0.8  knitr_1.14      
[11] digest_0.6.10    lattice_0.20-34
```

and

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] glmnet_2.0-2    foreach_1.4.3   Matrix_1.2-7.1  devtools_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1       R6_2.2.0         tools_3.3.1      withr_1.0.2      curl_2.1        
 [6] memoise_1.0.0    codetools_0.2-15 grid_3.3.1       iterators_1.0.8  digest_0.6.10   
[11] lattice_0.20-34
```

Comment: This seems rather complicated. Why do you have y_codings when you already have y_true? What's the difference?

Comment: you do not observe y_true, but have some human coders that are coding y based on x, with some precision. @HongOoi

Comment: Changing random seed fixed it for me: https://github.com/lmweber/glmnet-error-example/blob/master/glmnet_error_example.R

Comment: I am getting the same error using `glmnet_2.0-5` in a similar situation using ridge logistic regression. As the comment mentions in https://github.com/lmweber/glmnet-error-example/blob/master/glmnet_error_example.R, after stepping through the code it is to do with `mlami` being larger than all `lambda` values. Has this bug been made clear to the `glmnet` developers?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error in glmnet_2.0-5
It has something to do with how are the lambdas automatically created in some situations. The solution is to provide own lambdas

E.g:

```
cv.glmnet(x = X,
          y = expanded_data$y_codings,
          family="binomial", 
          alpha=0,
          lambda=exp(seq(log(0.001), log(5), length.out=100)))
```

Kudos to https://github.com/lmweber/glmnet-error-example/blob/master/glmnet_error_example.R

Comment: It still exists in `2.0.16` (obtained in a similar situation).

Comment: Same problem with `2.0.16` on `R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)`

Answer (score 3):

Well, I just ran the first loop and it completed successfully. This is with glmnet 2.0.2.

This is more of a comment, but it's too big to fit: when running tests like this which depend on random numbers, you can save the seed as you go. This lets you jump to the middle of the testing without having to go back to the start each time.

Something like this:

```
results <- lapply(1:1000, function(x) {
    seed <- .Random.seed
    res <- try(glmnet(x, y, ...))  # so the code keeps running even if there's an error
    attr(res, "seed") <- seed
    res
})
```

Now you can check if any of the runs failed, by looking at the class of the results:

```
errs <- sapply(results, function(x) inherits(x, "try-error"))
any(errs)
```

And you can retry those runs that failed:

```
firstErr <- which(errs)[1]
.Random.seed <- attr(results[[firstErr]], "seed")
glmnet(x, y, ...)  # try failed run again
```

---

Session info:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.850    
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] glmnetUtils_0.55    RevoUtilsMath_8.0.3 RevoUtils_8.0.3     RevoMods_8.0.3      RevoScaleR_8.0.6   
[6] lattice_0.20-33     rpart_4.1-10       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Matrix_1.2-2     parallel_3.2.2   codetools_0.2-14 rtvs_1.0.0.0     grid_3.2.2      
[6] iterators_1.0.8  foreach_1.4.3    glmnet_2.0-2
```

(That should be Windows 10, not 8; R 3.2.2 doesn't know about Win10)