# Crash in glmnet ridge logistic regression

Tags: r, glmnet

I obtain random crashes in package glmnet (versions 2.0.10 and 2.0.13, at least), trying to run cv.glmnet with a ridge logistic regression. A reproducible example is provided below. As you will see, the behaviour depends on the chosen random seed.

The error occurs in `cv.lognet()` because sometimes `nlami==0`. This is due to the fact that the range of the global (not cross-validated) lambda sequence (i.e. [14.3;20.7] in the example below) is entirely smaller than the range of lambda on one of the folds (i.e. fold 4, [32.5; 22.4])

A possible fix would be to force `nlami>=1` by changing the definition of `which_lam` as follows:

```
which_lam = lambda >= min(mlami, max(lambda))
```

This would avoid the crash, but not sure whether correctness of the results is ensured. Can anybody confirm or propose another fix?

NB: seems related to unresolved question [cv.glmnet fails for ridge, not lasso, for simulated data with coder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145209)

### Reproducible example

```
library(glmnet)

x=structure(c(0.294819653005975, -0.755878041644385, -0.460947383309942, 
  -1.25359210780316, -0.643969512320233, -0.146301489038128, -0.190235360501265, 
  -0.778418128295596, -0.659228201713315, -0.589987067456389, 1.33064976036166, 
  -0.232480434360983, -0.374383490492533, -0.504817187501063, -0.558531620483801, 
  2.16732105550181, 0.238948891919474, -0.857229316573454, -0.673919980092841, 
  1.17924306872964, 0.831719897152008, -1.15770770325374, 2.54984789196214, 
  -0.970167597835476, -0.557900637238063, -0.432268012373971, 1.15479761345536, 
  1.72197312745038, -0.460658453148444, -1.17746101934592, 0.411060691690596, 
  0.172735774511478, 0.328416881299735, 2.13514661730084, -0.498720272451663, 
  0.290967756655844, -0.87284566376257, -0.652533179632676, -0.89323787137697, 
  -0.566883371886824, -1.1794485033936, 0.821276174960557, -0.396480750015741, 
  -0.121609740429242, -0.464060359619162, 0.0396628676584573, -0.942871230138644, 
  0.160331360905244, -0.369955203694528, -0.192318421900764, -1.39309898491775, 
  -0.264395753844046, 2.25142560078458, -0.897873918532094, -0.159680604037913, 
  -0.918027468751383, 0.43181753901048, 1.56060286954228, -0.617456504201816, 
  1.73106033616784, -0.97099289786049, -1.09325650121771, -0.0407358272757967, 
  0.553103582991963, 1.15479545417553, 0.36144086171342, -1.35507249278068, 
  1.37684903500442, 0.755599287825675, 0.820363089698391, 1.65541232241803, 
  -0.692008406375665, 1.65484854848556, -1.14659093945895), .Dim = c(37L, 2L))

# NB: x is already standardized
print(apply(x,2,mean))
print(apply(x,2,sd))

y=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)

# NB: y is moderately unbalanced
print(table(y))

# This works OK (with a warning):
set.seed(3)
m = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE, type.measure = "class", nfolds = 5)

# This crashes:
set.seed(1)
m = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE, type.measure = "class", nfolds = 5)
# Error in predmat[which, seq(nlami)] <- preds : 
#     replacement has length zero
```

EDIT: visualization of data shows no specific pattern. Expect a low performance for a linear separator:
[image: Data plot: points positioned by 2 predictors, colored by label]

Comment: I think the problem is that during cross validation, there is a sample of data which has only a single response variable (y is all TRUE, or all FALSE) because you have so few observations.

Comment: @AidanGawronski: good point you raised. But I ran a debugger on `cv.glmnet` and it appears that all train sets have at least 8 instances of each class. In the test sets, the most unbalanced is 6 FALSE vs 1 TRUE.

On the other hand, the small number of observations makes cross-validation even more necessary

Comment: Pierre does my answer below help you?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that during cross validation, there is a sample of data which has only a single response variable (y is all TRUE, or all FALSE) because you have so few observations. With some random seeds you get lucky and this does not occur, but with the seed equal to 1 it does. My recommendation with so few observations would be to skip cross validation and just fit the model, then observe how changing lambda changes the coefficients:

```
lbs_fun <- function(fit, ...) {
  L <- length(fit$lambda)
  x <- log(fit$lambda[L])
  y <- fit$beta[, L]
  labs <- names(y)
  text(x, y, labels = labs, cex = 0.8, pos = 4)
}

m <- glmnet(x = x, y = y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial")
plot(m, xvar="lambda")
lbs_fun(m)
```

[image]

Note that this works with any seed (that I tested) without error.

Regarding your desire to evaluate prediction, this is how I would go about it, note that leave one out cross validation appears to be broken for the glmnet package, so had to be done manually here.

```
y <- y * 1 # I prefer 1 and 0, rather than true and false:
set.seed(1111) # set aside a holdout
holdout <- sample.int(37, 10)

x_train <- x[-holdout,]
y_train <- y[-holdout]
x_holdout <- x[holdout,]
y_holdout <- y[holdout]

# leave one out cross validation
out_df <- c()
run_num = 1
for(lambda_val in seq(0.001, 5, 0.1)) {
  for(one in 1:nrow(x_train)) {
    new_x = x_train[-one,] # train data minus one
    new_y = y_train[-one] # train data minus one
    one_x = x_train[one,,drop=FALSE] # leave one out
    one_y = y_train[one] # leave one out
    fit <- glmnet(x = new_x, y = new_y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial", standardize = F, lambda = lambda_val)
    y_hat <- predict(fit, one_x, type = "response")
    row <- c(run_num, lambda_val, y_hat, one_y)
    out_df <- rbind(out_df, row)
  }
  run_num <- run_num + 1
}
row.names(out_df) <- NULL
out_df <- data.frame(out_df)
names(out_df) <- c("run_number", "lambda", "y_hat", "y_actual")

# choose an evaluation metric: Accuracy (TN + TP)/(N + P), you will need to tune this threshold to best align with your metric
out_df$y_hat2 <- ifelse(out_df$y_hat >= 0.3, 1, 0)

get_best_run <- c()
for (run in unique(out_df$run_number)) {
  sub <- out_df[out_df$run_number == run, c("y_hat2", "y_actual")]
  accuracy <- nrow(sub[sub$y_hat2 == sub$y_actual,])/nrow(sub)
  row <- c(run, accuracy)
  get_best_run <- rbind(get_best_run, row)
}
row.names(get_best_run) <- NULL
get_best_run <- data.frame(get_best_run)
names(get_best_run) <- c("run_num", "accuracy")

# find the run number with the best accuracy
keep <- get_best_run[get_best_run$accuracy == max(get_best_run$accuracy), "run_num"]
keep_lambda <- unique(out_df[out_df$run_number == keep, "lambda"])

# fit a model with all of the train data (no cv here), and use the keep_lambda
fit <- glmnet(x = x_train, y = y_train, alpha = 0, family = "binomial", standardize = F, lambda = keep_lambda)

# make a prediction for the holdout + apply the same threshold used earlier
preds <- predict(fit, x_holdout, type = "response")
preds2 <- ifelse(preds >= 0.3, 1, 0)

# how can we expect this model to perform?
conf_mat <- table(preds2, y_holdout)
(conf_mat[1,1] + conf_mat[2,2])/sum(conf_mat) # accuracy 0.3

conf_mat
#        y_holdout
# preds2 0 1
#      0 3 2
#      1 5 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this won't crash because it bypasses the cross-validation which was responsible for the initial error. In the end, I'm interested in the model predictions rather than it formula. So how can I choose the best lambda? And how can I evaluate the performances of this solution?

Comment: @PierreGramme I think that your question is better suited to the [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) exchange perhaps with a question asking how best to make predictions on very small datasets. That being said, the above is how I would approach this task. Furthermore leave one out cross validation appears to be broken in the glmnet package, so perhaps the implementation above might help. Finally I would note that the best lamba for accuracy in the example above was the smallest one amongst all of the tested lambdas, which essentially is just logistic regression.

Comment: @PierreGramme ... does this help?